# Can I use EventBridge content filtering on a list of objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to use eventbridge content filtering to trigger a lambda function based on the RunTask event.  I only want this lambda to trigger if the `launch-type` field is `FARGATE`.  My issue is that the RunTask response returns a list of tasks that each have a launch-type, and I can't find any syntax for a filter that evaluates a list of objects.  Even a check if any one of them is FARGATE would be sufficient.